# C ZeroMQ zstr_recv hangs

Tags: c, zeromq

I have two simple programs: a client and a server. I'm trying to use zstr_sendfm and zstr_recv to send and receive a simple string. Roughly speaking, I'm using the code from the [file transfer test](http://zguide.zeromq.org/c:fileio3) in the zeromq tutorial. Here's the server function:

```
#define PIPELINE = 10;

int server()
{
    char *name = "someName";
    zctx_t *ctx = zctx_new();
    void *router = zsocket_new(ctx, ZMQ_ROUTER);
    zsocket_set_hwm(router, PIPELINE*2);
    if (0 == zsocket_connect(router, tcp://127.0.0.1:6000))
    {
        printf("failed to connect to router.\n");
    }
    printf( "sending name %s\n, name);
    zstr_sendfm( router, name );
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the client function:

```
int client()
{
    zctx_t *ctx = zctx_new ();
    void *dealer = zsocket_new (ctx, ZMQ_DEALER);
    zsocket_bind(dealer, "tcp://*:6000")
    char *receivedName = zstr_recv( dealer );
    printf("received the following name: %s\n", receivedName);
    return 0
}
```

Both of these are run in two separate programs (which do nothing other than run their respective functions) on the same computer.

Here's how things always play out:

1. Start client function, which holds at "zstr_recv" as it's supposed to
2. Start server function, which connects successfully, claims to have sent the data, and exits
3. Client function continues to sit and wait, but claims to have not received anything from the server.

What am I missing here? I've added a bunch of error checking and even tried this out in gdb with no luck.

Help and advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your client and server mixed up, although in ZeroMQ client and server is not as strict as with normal sockets. Normally you would create a server with a REP socket that binds/receives/sends and a client with a REQ socket that connects/sends/receives. You should try this first and then experiment with ROUTER for the server (instead of REP) and DEALER for the client (instead of REQ).

Comment: Agreed, I always send first from a client. Start by sending a version number from a client to the server and the server replying with its version number, then both the client and server know how to communicate.